# Java script hide/show makes stuff move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically my problem is that i have a function for javascript which makes new bars to appear when i hover over menu bar.
It works good however all stuff below changes it's position horizontally i am guessing because it detects new menu bars and applies margin top attribute in respect to new bars instead of original menu.

What i want it to stop moving when new menu bars appear, those new menu bars are hidden before i hover on my original menu, so maybe making margin-top attribute detect hidden stuff would be nice.

I wasn't sure how to explain it shortly for search, so sorry if it was already answred.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#portofolio").hover(function(){
        $("#hideshow").removeClass('hidden');
        }, function(){
    $("#hideshow").addClass('hidden');
    });
      $("#hideshow").hover(function(){
        $("#hideshow").removeClass('hidden');
        }, function(){
    $("#hideshow").addClass('hidden');
    });
})
```

Comment: Show us your code to clarify your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  your bar is showing on hover it's obvious that all the content bellow will make space for the new bar and everything below will shift little lower, if you want to show bar without moving content then you have to make  the bar top to all other content by this way new bar just will be visible and all other content will not move their postion

Comment: Yeah this worked, for those who don't know apperently it's done in css by using z-index property. Thank you very much!